# I Cannot reference a table in my database context in MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

An unused table exists in the database. Now I want to use it.
I am trying to insert a row into it but I get an error on the Add method.

> Error CS1061  'GalleryContext' does not contain a definition for
>   'tblPayPalTransactions' and no extension method
>   'tblPayPalTransactions' accepting a first argument of type
>   'GalleryContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly
>   reference?)   SurfJohn    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SurfJohn\Controllers\HomeController.cs   350

Here is the line that the error points to (Add(model)):

```
   // Save record to database

    db.tblPayPalTransactions.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

This is at the top of my Home Controller class and works on existing table.

```
  DAL.GalleryContext db = new DAL.GalleryContext();
```

So I go find GalleryContext. But I can't seem to add the model I created,  PayPalTransactions.cs, where I have put all the field definitions for the table "tblPayPalTransactions". I can manipulate the "Photo" table, not the tblPayPalTransactions :

```
namespace SurfJohn.DAL
{
    public class GalleryContext : DbContext
    {
        public GalleryContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<GalleryContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is database first design.

**EDIT:**
If I put my cursor over the db.tblPayPalTransactions.Add(model); (the table name is underlined in red), I get these 3 choices for potential fixes:

Generate field 'tblPayPalTransactions' in GalleryContext

Generate read-only field 'GalleryContext.tblPayPalTransactions'

Generate property 'GalleryContext.tblPayPalTransactions'

Comment: Does your database has table with name **tblPayPalTransactions** ? I think your database has table name as **PayPalTransaction(s)** and hence your line should be db.PayPalTransactions.Add(model).

Comment: No, sorry. It is tblPayPalTransactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a property of type `DbSet<PayPalTransactions>` on your `DbContext` to make it work. You already did the same with `Photos`.

```
public DbSet<PayPalTransactions> tblPayPalTransactions { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried that. Plural and singular. Photos table uses Photo: public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
but still get error 'GalleryContext does not contain a definition for 'tblPayPalTransactions' and no extension method 'tblPayPalTransactions' accepting a first aruguement of type 'GalleyContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?). I can't in my last 20 years I can't figure out how to add a row to a table with this MVC stuff. The table is viewable in VS 2015 Server Explorer window.

Comment: lol :) Did you add the property in your DbContext class? Becasue the error should not be the same.

Comment: Yep. That's it.

Comment: no, still isn't working.Error on  db.SaveChanges() line:Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.PayPalTransactions'.

Comment: So you need to make sur that the table with this name exist on your database and there is no typo error on your table name also.